# CListView DeleteColumn() deletes the wrong column

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc

I have CListView that I've subclassed an owner-drawn CHeaderCtrl so I can do things like have a popup menu allowing the user to select or de-select columns to display, move the columns around, change the width on columns, and display a sort-order icon on the header. 99% of it is working nicely.

My problem is that if I drag a column to a different place and then immediately right click and de-select a column from my pop up menu, I can't reliably figure out which column to delete. I have set the iSubItem field to my field identifier. I've tried using the physical offset to delete, I've also tried using GetColumn() to find my iSubItem number and get the iOrder and use that to delete. Either way, it isn't reliable.

If I *click* on a column header first, DeleteColumn() is dead reliable using the actual offset. Examining the data, it seems that the control gets the iOrder synchronized with the actual order once it has been clicked on.

I've tried calling Invalidate() on both the HeaderCtrl and the main list but that doesn't help. I think there's something I need to do to get things back in synch but after spending hours mucking around, I'm at wit's end.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: It's hard to understand this without MCVE. Maybe `CHeaderCtrl::OrderToIndex` will help.

Comment: Forgive me for not posting the code, it is pretty complex at this point, I felt that it might muddy the waters.

You nailed it though. Thank you SO much for taking the time to post your thoughts on it.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments,

Indeed, `CHeaderCtrl::OrderToIndex()` solved the problem.

Because I was using `GetColumn()` to retrieve the order associated with my SubItem value, passing the order to `OrderToIndex` gave me the appropriate index to pass to `DeleteColumn()`